# how to tell mpv to NOT play subtitles which may be embedded in a media file.

Tags: debian, shell, configuration, mpv

While I have asked quite a few questions about how to run subtitles in movies, this time though it's the opposite, how do I tell mpv not to load subtitle file while playing a media file. The media file is structured something like this -

```
Format                                   : Matroska
Format version                           : Version 4 / Version 2
File size                                : 3.67 GiB
Duration                                 : 2 h 40 min
Overall bit rate                         : 3 270 kb/s
Movie name                               : 
Encoded date                             : UTC 2016-02-29 16:33:21
Writing application                      : mkvmerge v8.9.0 ('Father Daughter') 64bit
Writing library                          : libebml v1.3.3 + libmatroska v1.4.4

Video
ID                                       : 1
Format                                   : AVC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile                           : High@L4.1
Format settings                          : CABAC / 5 Ref Frames
Format settings, CABAC                   : Yes
Format settings, ReFrames                : 5 frames
Codec ID                                 : V_MPEG4/ISO/AVC
Duration                                 : 2 h 40 min
Bit rate                                 : 2 500 kb/s
Width                                    : 1 920 pixels
Height                                   : 816 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 2.35:1
Frame rate mode                          : Constant
Frame rate                               : 24.000 FPS
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Scan type                                : Progressive
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 0.066
Stream size                              : 2.80 GiB (76%)
Title                                    : 
Writing library                          : x264 core 146 r2538 121396c
Encoding settings                        : cabac=1 / ref=5 / deblock=1:-1:-1 / analyse=0x3:0x113 / me=umh / subme=10 / psy=1 / psy_rd=1.00:0.07 / mixed_ref=1 / me_range=24 / chroma_me=1 / trellis=2 / 8x8dct=1 / cqm=0 / deadzone=21,11 / fast_pskip=0 / chroma_qp_offset=-3 / threads=12 / lookahead_threads=2 / sliced_threads=0 / nr=1000 / decimate=1 / interlaced=0 / bluray_compat=0 / constrained_intra=0 / bframes=8 / b_pyramid=2 / b_adapt=2 / b_bias=0 / direct=3 / weightb=1 / open_gop=0 / weightp=2 / keyint=240 / keyint_min=24 / scenecut=40 / intra_refresh=0 / rc_lookahead=60 / rc=2pass / mbtree=1 / bitrate=2500 / ratetol=1.0 / qcomp=0.60 / qpmin=0 / qpmax=69 / qpstep=4 / cplxblur=20.0 / qblur=0.5 / vbv_maxrate=62500 / vbv_bufsize=78125 / nal_hrd=none / filler=0 / ip_ratio=1.40 / aq=1:1.00
Language                                 : Hindi
Default                                  : Yes
Forced                                   : No
Color range                              : Limited
Color primaries                          : BT.709
Transfer characteristics                 : BT.709
Matrix coefficients                      : BT.709

Audio
ID                                       : 2
Format                                   : DTS
Format/Info                              : Digital Theater Systems
Codec ID                                 : A_DTS
Duration                                 : 2 h 40 min
Bit rate mode                            : Constant
Bit rate                                 : 768 kb/s
Channel(s)                               : 6 channels
Channel positions                        : Front: L C R, Side: L R, LFE
Sampling rate                            : 48.0 kHz
Frame rate                               : 93.750 FPS (512 SPF)
Bit depth                                : 24 bits
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Stream size                              : 882 MiB (23%)
Title                                    : 
Language                                 : Hindi
Default                                  : Yes
Forced                                   : No

Text
ID                                       : 3
Format                                   : UTF-8
Codec ID                                 : S_TEXT/UTF8
Codec ID/Info                            : UTF-8 Plain Text
Duration                                 : 2 h 30 min
Bit rate                                 : 42 b/s
Count of elements                        : 1825
Stream size                              : 47.1 KiB (0%)
Title                                    : 
Language                                 : English
Default                                  : Yes
Forced                                   : No
```

Now I want to be able to play the media file but **NOT** to play the subtitles at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the `mpv(1)` man page:

```
   --sid=<ID|auto|no>
          Display the subtitle stream specified by <ID>. auto selects  the
          default, no disables subtitles.
```

Answer (score 1):

Select "Next Subtitle track" from subtitle menu. It will disable automatically if media has only 1 subtitle embedded into it, if more than 2 than keep clicking "Next Subtitle track" until it says Subtitles:NO !!!